# How to replace ones with the values present in x?

Tags: python

In place of 1 , x values should be filled according to the index.

My code is :

x = [0.5697071  0.47144773 0.45310486]
z_prime= [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1]]

flatten_matrix = [val for val in z_prime ]
for val in flatten_matrix:
for j in val:
if(j!=0):
z= x
else:
z = 0
print(z)

This gives the output as:

0

0

0

0

0

[0.5697071  0.47144773 0.45310486]

0

[0.5697071  0.47144773 0.45310486]

0

0

[0.5697071  0.47144773 0.45310486]

[0.5697071  0.47144773 0.45310486]

Expected Output:
[ [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0.45310486 ], [0, 0.47144773 , 0], [0, 0.47144773, 0.45310486],

Comment: Please format your question the right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```py
flatten_matrix = [[x[idx] if elm[idx] == 1 else 0 for idx in range(len(elm))] for elm in z_prime]
```

As a sidenote: I'd recommend breaking this up into a standalone function, because if you ever come back to this list comprehension it'll be incomprehensible.
Consider something like this (which may be sligthly less performant, but much more readable)

```py
def flatten_matrix(x, z_prime):
    if len(x) != len(z_prime[0]):
        raise ValueError("x and z_prime must have the same number of columns")
    #Maybe even add a check here that all the elements of z_prime are 0 or 1
    #Or add a check that all elements in z_prime have the same length?
    output = [[0] * len(x) for i in range(len(z_prime))] #Creates the output list with correct format
    for row_idx, elm in enumerate(z_prime): #Iterates through the rows of z_prime
        for col_idx, num in enumerate(elm): #Iterates through the columns of z_prime
            if num == 1:
                output[row_idx][col_idx] = x[col_idx]
            else:
                output[row_idx][col_idx] = 0
    return output
```